# Google Maps Changing Center based on a list of Cities on Rails App - Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I apologize for the newbie question. I'm still figuring out the Google Maps API V3 as well as picking up Rails. I'm trying to change the center of the Google Map every time a user selects a different city from a drop down list. For eg., if a user selects New York City the map is centered on NYC and if they then choose Chicago it changes to Chicago. I was able to make this work for locations like Starbucks with respect to markers but can't seem to do it for cities.**At the moment, when I load the page no map appears - however, if  i remove  getCityOnSelect: function(){ - then the map appears**  I have listed all my relevant code below. Thank you so much for your help.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :city %><br>
<select name="item[city_id]" id="item_city_id">
    <option></option>
    <% City.all.each do |city| %>
        <option value="<%= city.id %>" data-lat1="<%= city.latitude %>" data-lng1="<%= city.longitude %>"><%= city.name %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :location %><br>
<select name="item[location_id]" id="item_location_id">
    <option></option>
    <% Location.all.each do |location| %>
        <option value="<%= location.id %>" data-lat="<%= location.latitude %>" data-lng="<%= location.longitude %>"><%= location.name %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

**seeds.rb**

```
City.destroy_all
nyc = City.create!(name:"New York City", latitude: 40.7128, longitude: -74.0059)
sf = City.create!(name:"San Francisco", latitude: 37.7749, longitude: -122.4194)
austin = City.create!(name:"Austin", latitude: 30.2672, longitude: -97.7431)
la = City.create!(name:"Los Angeles", latitude: 34.0522, longitude: -118.2437)
Location.destroy_all
starbuck = nyc.locations.create!(name: "Starbucks", latitude: 40.7435331, longitude: -73.9182956)
thinkcofee = nyc.locations.create!(name: "Think Coffee", latitude: 40.751, longitude: -73.992)
```

**coffeeController.js**

```
CoffeeController = {

initialize: function() {
this.createMap();
this.getLocationOnSelect();
this.getCityOnSelect(); 
},

markers: [],    
createMap: function(){
    getCityOnSelect: function(){
    $("#item_city_id").change(function(e){
        console.log(e);

    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    lng = parseFloat($( this ).data('lng1'))
    lat = parseFloat($( this ).data('lat1'))        
    });
    })  
},
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
center: getCityOnSelect,
zoom: 11,
mapTypeControl: false
});
},

getLocationOnSelect: function(){
$("#item_location_id").change(function(e){
console.log(e);

    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    lng = parseFloat($( this ).data('lng'))
    lat = parseFloat($( this ).data('lat'))
    CoffeeController.createmarker(lat, lng)
});
})
},
destroyMarkers: function(){
    for(var i=0; i< this.markers.length; i++){
        this.markers[i].setMap(null)
    }   
},
createmarker: function(lat, lng){
    this.destroyMarkers();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: lat, lng: lng},
      map: map

    });
CoffeeController.markers.push(marker)
}
}
function initMap(){
CoffeeController.initialize();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the center of the maps to function, getCityOnSelect, rather than a google.maps.LatLng or a lat/lng literal object.  I believe you meant to invoke that function, which, by the way, doesn't seem to be correctly defined, nor does it return anything.